# How to do load AllowHTML in handsontable0.8.13

Tags: jquery, handsontable

how to do this in 0.8.13

```
var data = [
["<input type='checkbox' name='selectall' class='headchecker'>", "Pallet Barcode", "Com", "Form", "Size", "Grade", "Brand", "Fineness", "Serial", "Gross", "Net", "Fine Oz", "Original Weight","selectall"]];

$("#silverBarList").handsontable("loadData", data,true);
```

In previous versions it worked fine.
But in this 0.8.13 the checkbox is not coming instead that test only displaying.

How to do this..?

Answer (score 0):

Use column settings and set type to checkbox.

```
$("#silverBarList").handsontable({
    data : data,
    columns : [
        { type : 'checkbox' }
    ]
});
```

Or you can use custom renderer for that. For more info about them look at this example page: http://handsontable.com/demo/renderers_html.html